# How to color format duplicates in a column with unique colors for unique values in Excel?

Tags: excel, colors, formatting

I have a column with multiple duplicates.

Is there a simple way, to have the unique values filled with the same unique colors?

Ex. if I have this column

```
Col A
a
a
a
b
b
b
c
c
c
```

the a values will be filled with yellow, the b values filled with red, the c values filled with green. But I don't know the "exact text" values (He in the example I know the value 'a', 'b' and 'c'. But in reality I don't know the exact text. I just know there are duplicates). So this must be generic..

Comment: Will all values be sorted as in your example, or will they appear randomly (i.e. `a, a, a, b, b, b, c, c, c` or `a, b, a, c, b, c, c, a, b`)? If the former would alternating between two colours be OK?

Comment: You'll probably need VBA for this. Simple way - no.

Comment: If you can forego "unique" colors for each, you can use conditional formatting for each row, e.g., to check A3's value above `=match(A3,$A$1:$A2,0)` and where true add color.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad yes, alternating between two colors would be Okay! They are sorted. An answer for unsorted as well would be also acceptable, if it is not much work to write :) But for now, for sorted and alternating just 2 colors it will be okay :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires that the first row is a header and data must be sorted:

Use conditional formatting with the following formula:

```
=ISODD(SUMPRODUCT(--(A$2:A2<>A$1:A1)))
```